# Windows: Lid close action set to do nothing, still sleeps after a time with lid closed while in use

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, power-management

On my Asus ZenBook UM425I (AKA UX425IA) with Windows 10 Build 19043, everything is working very nicely except as follows.  **My lid close action is set to always "do nothing"** per screenshot below, and when the PC is in regular use, with the **lid closed**, plugged in to a USB 3.2 monitor with Power Delivery, and thus charging, **it will, after maybe ten minutes or an hour, go to sleep**.  I could be in the middle of work, playing a game, or browsing, and the PC just goes to sleep without warning or context.  I can lift the lid and press power to bring it back.

I jumped to the idea that maybe it was overheating (and thus there was something worse to investigate), but Speedfan was showing reasonable temperatures right before the sleep.

When I leave the lid open, everything works fine and it never sleeps while I am using it.

What else can I troubleshoot to make it stay on?  Below are my lid settings and `powercfg` output.  In the `powercfg` output, it does not show `(Lid close action)` as a power setting at all--could this be related to the problem?   Note that the laptop indeed does nothing on lid close, but only sleeps quite some time later.

[image: Power Options with lid close action]

```
C:\>powercfg -getactivescheme
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)
C:\>powercfg -q 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)
  GUID Alias: SCHEME_BALANCED
 
  (... other Subgroups removed ...) 

  Subgroup GUID: 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20  (Sleep)
    GUID Alias: SUB_SLEEP
    Power Setting GUID: 29f6c1db-86da-48c5-9fdb-f2b67b1f44da  (Sleep after)
      GUID Alias: STANDBYIDLE
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0xffffffff
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: Seconds
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00002a30
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x000004b0

  Subgroup GUID: 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347  (Power buttons and lid)
    GUID Alias: SUB_BUTTONS
    Power Setting GUID: a7066653-8d6c-40a8-910e-a1f54b84c7e5  (Start menu power button)
      GUID Alias: UIBUTTON_ACTION
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Sleep
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Hibernate
      Possible Setting Index: 002
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Shut down
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
```

UPDATE:  I just ran `powercfg -attributes SUB_BUTTONS 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 -ATTRIB_HIDE` from an adminstrator command prompt and now `(Lid close action)` appears in the `powercfg` output as below. It appears to be set properly.  It did not make any difference; the PC still sleeps in the middle of usage.

```
  Subgroup GUID: 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347  (Power buttons and lid)
    GUID Alias: SUB_BUTTONS
    Power Setting GUID: 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936  (Lid close action)
      GUID Alias: LIDACTION
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Do nothing
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Sleep
      Possible Setting Index: 002
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Hibernate
      Possible Setting Index: 003
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Shut down
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
```

Comment: I could be in the middle of work, playing a game, or browsing, and the PC just goes to sleep without warning or context.   <- Update BIOS, Chipset, Power Drivers, restart, set Windows Power Management to Default, restart and try setting just Lid Close = Nothing and test.

Comment: Any idea where I should get the drivers?  I don't see a page for the UX425IA on [Asus's site](https://www.asus.com/us/support/).  Note this is the AMD version of the UX425, not Intel.

Comment: I see, Windows sees it as a UX425IA but it is actually a UM425I.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Updating drivers didn't help.

Comment: Some tries: (1) Create a new power scheme ([link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/43655-create-custom-power-plan-windows-10-a.html)), (2) Uninstall Instant On from Asus (if installed).

Comment: boot into safe mode and see if it makes a difference. I suspect there is some 3rd party power saving going on. Also does this happen if the lid is opened and PC idle for some time?

Comment: Sleep-after/StandbyIdle DC (battery) setting is set to a time meaning on idle it'll sleep after this amount of time. I suspect Windows is ONLY using your lid closed as an idle indicator & sleeping. Turn that off (change to 0) to see if that helps. It SHOULD be using other 'idle' indicators which we can investigate once we determine that IS THE CAUSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a significant amount of heat is dissipated through the metal rear of the bottom part, which is blocked when the lid is closed.

Also, keeping the bottom of a firm surface to allow airflow into the tiny vent holes underneath is important.  When I do that, it does not sleep, so I believe **overheating** is indeed the problem and **while I work I need to keep the lid open to allow for cooling**, especially from the hot zone just above (behind) the keyboard.